# Nativescript acces sdcard camera module image directory

Tags: camera, nativescript, imagesource

My question is related to this documentation about camera module: https://docs.nativescript.org/hardware/camera

It's saving files on /sdcard/Android/data/applicationName/files/picname

How can I pull any of those images to use with image.imageSource?

Answer (score 1):

You could use native code to access the external storage of your device. You can review the given code snippet.

```
var appModule = require("application");
var tempPicturePath = path.join(appModule .android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(appModule .android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath(), "imagename.png");
        console.log("extr storage "+tempPicturePath);
```

You could also review [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/365) issue in GitHub and this [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).